# My function returned a string. How to execute it?

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql

My function `fun()` returned a long crosstab table generation string (varchar) that I can view with `select fun()`. How to execute it not inside a function but from a console?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`\gexec` in psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) to execute what the query returns:

```
SELECT fun()\gexec
```

The manual:

> Sends the current query buffer to the server, then treats each column
> of each row of the query's output (if any) as an SQL statement to be executed.

[Read the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) for more details.

Related:

- [Simulate CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS for PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18389184/939860)

Comment: even if fun() returned  something like `SELECT * from...`?

Comment: @Blender: Yes. Follow the link to read details in the manual.

Comment: Yeah it does not work in datagrip console sadly for me…