# Is there a function that adds together all numeric columns in a row?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, dynamic-sql

Using Postgres 15, how to get a sum of columns in each row from a table ?

```
-86750 | 1728 | 1500 | 61.69 | 415 |      130.18 |   303.99 | 288.57 |        93.44 |         78.06 |              0 |    561.69 |              257.49
-86100 |  798 |  700 |    68 | 415 |         130 |      303 |    288 |          128 |            20 |              0 |       561 |                 257
```

In particular, I want to add together values of columns that have the `int` or `float` data types,  instead of referencing their names.

I mean not using something like:

```
for each row ....
     select toto+tata+titi+tutut from .... where rawid=....
```

But something more like:

```
for each row 
     if column is type float or int 
        variable+= it 
     fi
```

Is this possible?

Comment: No such built-in instruments. Of course you may find some workaround (something like subquery - row_to_json - parse - aggregate), but I doubt that this is reasonable.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for as a procedure/macro or something similar

Comment: What for? Just do `a + b + c +...`

Comment: you didn't understood the question @Charlieface ; solution must feat on column type detection not on only values

Comment: Why can't you just name the columns one by one?

Comment: cause I will never know them in my use case ; I will access a permanantly moving data set the only thing constant is table name in fact so it may contain anything & I will use numeric values only I cannot say more publically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [JSONB functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html). Note that this cannot differentiate between different types of numbers, only between numbers and strings.

```
SELECT
  (
    SELECT SUM(j::float)
    FROM to_jsonb(t) r
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_path_query(r, '$.* ? (@.type() == "number")') j
  )
FROM YourTable t
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/QZqKnxRV)

This does the following, all inside a subquery:

- First convert the whole row into JSONB
- Pull out each property value, where the property type is `number`, as separate rows
- Sum the data

The efficiency of this is going to be much worse than just naming each column explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your pudding and eat it, too. Meaning, you can have the result just naming the table, and still get optimal performance, building the command dynamically.

This builds your command:

```
SELECT format('SELECT %1$s AS my_sum FROM %2$s'
            , string_agg(quote_ident(a.attname), ' + ')
            , min(attrelid)::regclass
             )
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_type t ON t.oid = a.atttypid
WHERE  a.attrelid = 'my_schema.my_table'::regclass  -- provide table name here, optionally schema-qualified!
AND    a.attnum > 0                 -- only user columns
AND    NOT a.attisdropped           -- no dropped columns
AND    t.typcategory = 'N';         -- all "numeric" types
```

Notably safe against SQL injection. See:

- [Safely quoting type names to protect against SQL-injection](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203975/safely-quoting-type-names-to-protect-against-sql-injection/203988#203988)

Here I use the **psql** meta-command `\gexec` to immediately execute the built command:

```
test=> SELECT format('SELECT %1$s AS result FROM %2$s'
test(>             , string_agg(quote_ident(a.attname), ' + ')
test(>             , min(a.attrelid)::regclass
test(>              )
test-> FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
test-> JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_type t ON t.oid = a.atttypid
test-> WHERE  a.attrelid = 'my_table'::regclass
test-> AND    a.attnum > 0
test-> AND    NOT a.attisdropped
test-> AND    t.typcategory = 'N'\gexec
 result 
--------
     21
     23
       
     12
(4 rows)
```

See:

- [My function returned a string. How to execute it?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/300699/my-function-returned-a-string-how-to-execute-it/300700#300700)

Alternatively, create a function that executes dynamic SQL.

You may want to wrap columns that can be `null` into `COALESCE` to not nullify the sum (like demonstrated in row 3 of above example). And you may want to cast to `float8` (which can hold the sum of any numeric types) to get a consistent result type:

```
SELECT format('SELECT (%1$s)::float8 AS my_sum FROM %2$s'
            , string_agg(CASE WHEN a.attnotnull THEN quote_ident(a.attname) ELSE 'COALESCE(' || quote_ident(a.attname) || $$, '0')$$ END, ' + ')
            , min(a.attrelid)::regclass
             )
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_type t ON t.oid = a.atttypid
WHERE  a.attrelid = 'my_table'::regclass  -- provide table name here!
AND    a.attnum > 0
AND    NOT a.attisdropped
AND    t.typcategory = 'N'\gexec
```

The manual about [`pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html) and [`pg_type`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html).